# Python validating web forms data

Tags: python, forms, mod-wsgi, web, validating

I am able to extract the form field data, but I am NOT able to Put a check / validate the information to see if The field is not empty.

I am writing it in Apache+mod_wsgi, browser FF, Python 2.6, Ubuntu 10.04 64bit

The Following is the sample code where web form field data is read.This is where i need to put a check, whether if this field is EMPTY or NOT. If empty ,a default_error string for specific field, go back and fill in the data. Till then "Save" ( or "Print & Save") DOES NOT show.

```
state = form.getvalue('state')
nameDistrict = form.getvalue('district')
dist_code = form.getvalue('Dcode')

html += 'State :' + str(state)
html += 'District Name :' + str(nameDistrict)
html += 'District Code :' + str(dist_code)
```

The following  is one way I was trying, nAdA. :(

```
 def val(dict, key, default_str):
     value = dict.get(key, default_str)
     if value == '':
         return default_str
     else:
         return value
```

second attempt

```
if state == ' ' :
       return 'Please Enter the State Name'
else :
       return state
```

another trial was

```
try:
    state = form.getvalue('state')
except ValueError:
    'Please Enter the state Name'
```

No luck.

Please show by some examples by which I can put the check.

Thanks

Comment: Could you comment on the type or format of the "form" variable in your sample code?  Where is it coming from?  E.g. have you parsed the QUERY_STRING environ variable or converted the POST data to a dict-like object?

Answer (score 1):

This is the part of the code I am using.

> ```
>      class Handler:<br>
>           def do(self, environ, start_response):<br>
>           html = """
>           <html><head><title>C Informatics</title>
>           <meta charset=utf-8>
>           <form method="post" action="newreg.py"><br>
>           <table border=1><br>
>           <tr><td>State:-<input type="text" name="state" size=15 max length=15><br>
>           City/District:<input type="text" name="district">Code:<input type="text" > 
>           name="Dcode" max length=10 size=10>
>              . . . . . . . . .
> ```

```
     <input type="submit" Value="Save">
     <input type="submit" value="Print & Save"></center>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was also asked on mod_wsgi list and answer given there.

http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_thread/thread/97e1ab3bde4230a1#